# Shortcode content filter?

Tags: php, functions, shortcode

I'm looking for something, but don't exactly know what.

I have a shortcode, let's call it [shortcode].

Users will input HTML tags inside, mostly images, but also links, images in links, etc., for example:

```
[shortcode]
<img src="http://www.site.com/myimage.jpg" />
<a href="http://www.blabla.com"><img src="http://www.site.com/myimage2.jpg" /></a>
(...)
[/shortcode]
```

The point is I want to format URLs, differently, I want every img src to start with files/myimagescript?

So the code above should output:

```
<!--- shortcode code before input -->
<img src="files/myimagescript?http://www.site.com/myimage.jpg" />
    <a href="http://www.blabla.com"><img src="files/myimagescript?http://www.site.com/myimage2.jpg" /></a>
    (...)
<!-- shortcode code after input -->
```

So basically I need to simply change src of images. And it should work for any number of images, from 1 to unlimited.

I'm thinking about foreach PHP loop, but I'm not sure how to grab each img src line from shortcode and process it before displaying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use regex to find your the src and use that to append your "files/myimagescript?" to it:

```
function append_myimagescript($attr, $content){ 
    $pattern = '/src="([^"]*)"/i';
    $replacement = 'files/myimagescript?${1}';
    return preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
}
```

Comment: Pretty much the only way to... there's no way you'd match the image src's inside the post without a regex...(which should have you thinking.... is the approach i want to take)... If ever you **need** regex... it's usually the wrong way to approach it... (impo of course)...

Comment: +1 to Bainternet though... i was thnking out loud more than anything... :)

Comment: @t31os if you say so! I'm changing my approach then, if using Regex is the wrong thing :)

Comment: It's not the wrong way, i just think it's more ideal if you can find a way to tackle a problem without regex(they're not the fastest of operations). For this particular problem though regex is pretty much your only option.

Comment: I'd have to agree that if you find yourself depending on regex then that should be the last resort,  how about a short code that takes the image src as an attribute as an alternative?